# Problema com Weld CDI com o servidor TomCat

Tags: jsf-2.2, tomcat, cdi

Saudação para todos, estou com problema ao utilizar a implementação CDI, Weld no Tomcat 7. Já estive dando uma pesquisada e tentei várias soluções propostas, porém todas essas soluções são antigas, com datas de 2012. Nenhuma dessas soluções funcionaram.

**Vamos as configurações e versões:**

Versões: Tomcat 7, JSF 2.1, Weld 2.1.0.Final

**Configurações:**

beans.xml (src/META-INF/beans.xml): ARQUIVO EM BRANCO
context.xml (src/META-INF/context.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>  
   <Manager pathname=""/> <!-- disables storage of sessions across restarts -->  
   <Resource name="BeanManager"        
          auth="Container"      
          type="javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager"   
          factory="org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory"/>     
</Context>
```

Jar colocado como projeto Maven

http://seamframework.org/Weld/Home.html

```
<!-- Weld (implementação do CDI) -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.10.Final</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <resource-env-ref>
    <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
    <resource-env-ref-type>
        javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager
    </resource-env-ref-type>
  </resource-env-ref>
```

**SUBO O MEU TOMCAT E AO ENTRAR NO MEU index.xhtml, RECEBO O SEGUINTE ERRO:**

```
GRAVE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Singleton is not set
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.api.helpers.IsolatedStaticSingletonProvider$IsolatedStaticSingleton.get(IsolatedStaticSingletonProvider.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.Container.instance(Container.java:54)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.shutdown(WeldBootstrap.java:466)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener.contextDestroyed(Listener.java:83)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:5064)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5726)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Tente mover o `beans.xml` para `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF`. O `context.xml` você aponta com a propriedade [containerConfigXML](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#containerConfigXML) do WAR plugin. O objetIvo é que dentro do war os caminhos sejam respectivamente  `WEB-INF/beans.xml` e `META-INF/context.xml`.